# In GTK, how do I make a window unable to be closed?

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygtk

For example, graying out the "X" on windows systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Gtk can't convince the window manager you can always connect the "delete-event" signal and return True from the callback. Doing this Gtk assumes that the callback handle that signal and does nothing.

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window()
window.connect('delete-event',lambda widget, event: True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just call the `set_deletable` with `False` on the window in question. It will work as long as GTK can convince the window manager to make the window unclosable.

Comment: Why did you answer your own question in under a minute?

Comment: I don't know what happened here.  But I like it.

Comment: I had a question. then, before posting it here, I looked it up and found the answer in a few minutes. i figured i might as well add to the SO stash of questions by putting it up, along w/ an answer so as to not waste anyones time =P. vote me up!!@!# omg.